# mysql - union with creating demarcated field

Tags: mysql

I need UNION two tables with creating new field, where 1 for first table, and 2 for second.

I tried

```
(
    SELECT field, 1 AS tmp
    FROM table1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT field, 2 AS tmp
    FROM table2
)
```

But in result, tmp field was full of "1".

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work fine. The only thing you should change is `UNION` should be `UNION ALL` to give better performance. Without the `ALL` it defaults to `UNION DISTINCT` which causes the rows to be compared for duplicates*, but the way you have constructed them guarantees that there cannot be duplicates so this extra check is a waste of time. Here is some test code I used to verify that what you are doing ought to work:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (field NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (field) VALUES
('foo1'),
('bar1'),
('baz1');

CREATE TABLE table2 (field NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table2 (field) VALUES
('foo2'),
('bar2'),
('baz2');

SELECT field, 1 AS tmp
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT field, 2 AS tmp
FROM table2
```

Result:

```
'foo1', 1
'bar1', 1
'baz1', 1
'foo2', 2
'bar2', 2
'baz2', 2
```

If you only get rows where tmp was equal to 1, maybe your table2 was empty?

---

*See the [documentation for UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close

```
Create YourNewTable
SELECT field, 1 AS tmp 
    FROM table1 
UNION ALL
    SELECT field, 2 AS tmp 
    FROM table2
```